# Complex Text Animation Letter by Letter

Tags: javascript, animation, text, onscroll

I have two questions concerning multiple text animations: 
Is it possible to animate Text this way:

I prepared an [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ0vp.gif) in After Effects.

First my questions:
 1. I just want to let the Text appear. It shouldn't disappear afterwards.

2. How is it possible to start the animation when the text appears on screen by scrolling? -> on scroll

This snippet I found on Codepen: [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGaogv)

HTML:

```
    <div class="name">

  <div class="letter">e</div>
  <div class="letter">x</div>
  <div class="letter">a</div>
  <div class="letter">m</div>
  <div class="letter">p</div>
  <div class="letter">l</div>
  <div class="letter">e</div>

</div>
```

CS:

```
body {
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto;
    font-family:"Unica One";
    font-size: 4rem;
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  display:flex;
  .name {
    display:flex;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0 1rem 1rem;
    position: relative;

    .letter {
      display:inline-block;
      opacity:0;
      transform:scale(0.9);
    }
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var opac = anime({
  targets: '.letter',
    opacity:1,
  scale:1,
    easing:'easeInBounce',
    delay: function(el, index) {
      return index * 80;
    },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Question part 1:

For just to stop the looping, you could delete the properties `direction` and `loop`.

```js
var opac = anime({
    targets: '.letter',
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    easing: 'easeInBounce',
    delay: function(el, index) {
        return index * 80;
    },
    // direction: 'alternate', // stop vanishing
    // loop: true              // prevent looping
});
```

```css
html { height:100%; }
body { min-height:100%; height:auto; font-family:"Unica One"; font-size: 4rem; color:#fff; background:#000; display:flex; }
.name { display:flex; margin:auto; padding:0 1rem 1rem; position: relative; }
.letter { display:inline-block; opacity:0; transform:scale(0.9); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/1.0.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
  <div class="letter">e</div>
  <div class="letter">x</div>
  <div class="letter">a</div>
  <div class="letter">m</div>
  <div class="letter">p</div>
  <div class="letter">l</div>
  <div class="letter">e</div>
</div>
```